# Mouseleave/mouseenter and mousemove interfere, causing unwanted behavoir

Tags: jquery, mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm trying to animate a navigation using jquery. The initial state of the element is:

```
nav ul {
    margin-left: 150px }
```

When the mouse leaves the header it's supposed to move from right to left.
When the mouse enters the header it's supposed to move from left to right.

This alone works beautifully with the method I've worked with:

```
$('header')
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('nav ul').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 250 );
    })
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('nav ul').animate({ 'margin-left': '150px' }, 250 );
});
```

In case the user, after navigating to a different page, moves the mouse to the .main-wrapper section during the loading process, I want the navigation to move from right to left as well. I therefore thought about using mousemove() on the .main-wrapper as follows:

```
  $('.main-wrapper')
    .mousemove(function() {
        $('nav ul').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 250 );
  });
```

However when I do that the functions seem to interfere in a way that I do not understand. mouseenter() and mouseleave() seem to not work anymore and juts randomly "fire".
Can you help me understand this issue?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7Lzdzwq/)

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and add relevante HTML/CSS/Script in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish but here's the issue. When you leave the header with the mouse, it moves the margin back to 0px. You have to leave the header to go to the main content div so that action moves the margin back to 0px. Once you are in the main content div the mouse move does nothing since the margin is already 0px;

I think there may be some interference between the mousemove even on the main div and the enter event on the header however given what you have in mouse move on the main div and the fact that the mouse leave on the header does the same thing as the mouse move, I'd just remove the mouse move event.

Comment: Actually <ul> is supposed to hide behind an overlay div (which I had left out in the Fiddle since it didn't seem relevant to the question to me). So obviously I'm trying to hide the menu whenever it's not needed.
Imagine you're browsing the website with a slow connection. Now you're following a link from the menu. After clicking it and while waiting for the new page to load, you move the mouse to the main-wrapper.
When the page is finally loaded mouseleave() is not going to be executed, therefore <ul> is visible, which it shouldn't, since the mouse isn't hovering the header.

Comment: But once the page is loaded, doesn't the menu have the starting position you want so the mouseleave is not necessary?

Comment: I've set the starting position to margin-left: 150px. If I'd set it to 0px the menu would jump without animation to the hidden state whenever the user navigates to a different page - which is not the behavior I want. Especially this would cause the menu to hide when the mouse still hovers the header as well. (If that was no issue I could delay the href and make the menu move to the left before the new page loads.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with the following solution:

```
$('header')
.hover(function() {
    $('nav ul').animate({'margin-left': '425px' }, { duration: 200, queue : false });
});

$('.main-wrapper')
.hover(function() {
    $('nav ul').animate({'margin-left': '0px' }, { duration: 200, queue : false });
});
```